# Efficiency of parallel and sequential heat pumps

Tags: heat

Consider two identical heat pumps, for example, split-system air conditioners. There're two ways to make them work - in parallel or sequential. Parallel means that "hot" radiators of the machines are put outside the room, while the "cold" radiators are put inside the room. Sequential means that the cold radiator of the first machine is inside the room, while the hot radiator is put inside, say, a large isolated box, where it is cooled by the cold radiator of the second machine, and the hot radiator of the second machine is outside the room.

In which case - parallel or sequential - the efficiency of the cooling would be better?

Comment: Are you talking about heat engines or heat pumps?

Comment: The air conditioner (cooler) is actually a heat pump, so, yes, I'm talking about heat pumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efficiency of one heat pump in cooling can be defined by expression

$$\eta = \frac{Q_C}{W},$$

that is heat that is taken from cooler reservoir divided by the work put into the pump.

If you have two pumps in parallel efficiency shall be the same, as you will have heat twice as large and work twice as large

$$\eta = \frac{2Q_C}{2W}.$$

If you however have two pumps in sequence equation reads as

$$\eta = \frac{Q_C}{2W}.$$

So in order to obtain at least same efficiency you should extract heat twice as large by **each** pump.  So **the efficiency of each pump should be twice as large for about half of the temperature change**.  So far so easy.

In the next step we must take into consideration exact cyclical thermodynamical processes.  There are plenty of them that you can use and no can be exactly theoretically calculated.  In such cases it is useful to observe the most efficient thermodynamical process, that is Carnot cycle and extract conclusions from it.

Efficiency of the heat engine based on Carnot cycle can be shown to be

$$\eta = \frac{T_C}{T_H-T_C}.$$

In case of two pumps in the *first iteration* intermediate temperature $T' = \frac{T_C+T_H}{2}$ in exactly in the middle.  Efficiency of two pumps shall be

$$\eta_1 = \frac{T_C}{T'-T_C}, \eta_2 = \frac{T'}{T_H-T'}$$

Obviously $\eta_1 = 2 \eta$ and $\eta_2 > 2 \eta$, therefore two sequential pumps **in cooling** should be *more* efficient.

It is interesting that two sequential pumps **in warming** should be *less* efficient using the same arguments!  I cannot find the error in the reasoning, so before accepting the answer, please wait some time that others check and give their comments.

Comment: In case of sequential pumping you say that the amount of heat taken is the same as in case of parallel, but the heat exchanging is proportional to the temperature difference, and in sequential case the temperature differences are higher, so the amount of heat is not the same $Q_c$ for those cases.

Comment: @mbaitoff I didn't exaclty understand you, but I will try to guess what is the problem you are talking about.  If you have a heat pump and large temperature difference, the heat pump will extract only small amount of heat.  If you have small temperature difference, the heat pump shall extract larger abount of heat in the same period of time.  It is similar to rising 1kg to 10 m, and 10 kg to 1 m.  You need equal work to do both.

Comment: Heat pumping (in air conditioner) is achieved by subtracting the heat from the volume being cooled and by dissipating this heat into outer volume. Dissipating is only possible when coolant fluid temperature is lower than the outer volume temperature. When outdoor temperature rises, air conditioning becomes less effective and stops at all when those temperatures become equal, right? So, at the point of equilibrium $Q_c$ becomes zero, so $Q_c$ cannot be constant and depends on temperature difference. Am I right or am I missing something?

Comment: Dissipating is only possible when coolant fluid temperature is **higher** than the outer volume temperature.

Comment: If temperature difference is higher, then $Q_C$ effectively becomes smaller.  Of course, for real systems there is certain temperature difference for which $Q_C = 0$.  Theoretically this is possible only for infinite difference in temperatures

Comment: Sure, my mistake, the correct word is "higher", of course, but the question still stands.

Comment: The idea behind my answer is about ideal heat pumps that work regardless of the temperature difference.  Whatever, maybe my reasoning is OK, but I am still surprised by conclusions.  Especially because for heating the conclusion is opposite!

Comment: Also, I recall that the efficiency coefficient is higher if the temperature difference is higher. Your equations for efficiency look turned upside down.

Comment: We have to separate problems: First: real systems vs. ideal systems.  For example, heat engine is theoretically more efficient if the temperature of the cold reservoir (environment) are lower.  This is actually true for temperatures above 10C, but below this temperature engine becomes less efficient.  Other effects become important that are not included in the theory.  The second problem is pure theoretical reasoning.  It is unusual, theoretically that is, that different conclusions are drawn for heating and cooling.

Comment: Heat engines: I was talking about car engines.  They have some optimal efficiency about 10C, and this efficiency drops for higher and lower temperatures.  Higher temperatures: in accordance with simple theory.  Lower temperatures: not so.  Of course real systems are so complex that you actually use extremely complex simulations and programs to predict efficiency.  I know some of these guys and we discussed this topic considering car machines.

Comment: I'll be gone for some time: I suggest you don't accept answer as this might attract others to see the question and maybe give some other insights.  Too bad, there is not many engineers around, which would be helpful for your question.  If I find something new, I'll post here. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The COP of a heat pump is a function of temperature lift (change from source to destination).  The higher the lift the lower the COP.  30C lift at 300% COP a practical rule of thumb.  In paralel you can get twice the heat at a constant lift.  In series twice the lift for the same total heat generated at the same efficiency.  Higher (perhaps double) efficiency but the same total heat as a single heat pump can be achieved serially, by halving each's lift.

High lift is generally a limitation of heat pumps and so a serial arrangement is a method of overcomming those limitations.

Answer (score 0):

the heating COPtotal of the sequential heat pumps (hp) will be:

COPtotal = COP1*COP2/(COP1+COP2-1)

imagine a hp1(cop1 = 10) in series with hp2(cop2=10) with the resulting Q=1000W.

the work of hp2 = Q/cop2 = 1000/10=100W

This means the Qin of hp2 = 1000W-100W=900W

Qin for hp2 is Qout for hp1, the work of hp1 = Qin/cop1 = 900/10 = 90W

Now we see that for 1000W we put in 190W so 1000/190 = 5.26

So putting them sequential is not a matter of increasing the COP. You only do this because the temperature lift is to high for a single heat pump.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that we have a target temperature of $T_c$ and an exterior temperature of $T_c+\Delta T$ and we want to use two heat pumps to reach the target in roughly equal steps.  We assume that the amount of fluid used is the same in the two to keep the change in Q and T to be proportional. The temperature at the input to the second stage is $T_c + \Delta T/2$.  The energy used for the compressor is W. The heat removed in each step is $Q/2$.

The efficiency at each step is:
$$ \eta_1 = \frac{Q/2}{W_1},  \eta_2 = \frac{Q/2}{W2}$$
The overall efficiency is:
$$ \eta_{12} = \frac{Q}{W_1+W_2} = \frac{Q}{Q/(2\eta_1)+Q/(2\eta_2)} =\frac{2\eta_1\eta_2}{\eta_1+\eta_2}$$

One can already see that this will turn out well because, if the two efficiencies are roughly the same, then the overall efficiency is about that efficiency, and we know that taking smaller temperature steps is more efficient.

If we assume that the process follows closely to a perfect Carnot cycle, then:
$$ \eta_1 = \frac{T_c + \Delta T/2}{\Delta T/2}=\frac{2T_c}{\Delta T}+1 = 2\eta + 1$$
$$\eta_2 = \frac{T_c}{\Delta T/2}=\frac{2T_c}{\Delta T} = 2\eta$$
where $\eta$ is the efficiency (COP) of a single heat pump cooling to the target temperature alone.

Substituting back into the overall efficiency:
$$\eta_{12} = \left(2 + \frac{2}{4\eta+1}\right) \eta $$

An improvement of better than a factor of 2!